# Delete institute-space in title page (beamer class)

Tags: beamer

Using the beamer class, I designed the title page as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\title[]{This is the title.} 
\author{The name.}
\date{The date.}
\titlegraphic{
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth{titlegraphic.jpg}
\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, there is a big space between the name and the date, where usually the institute is set. How can I delete this space and move name and date closer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see to this is to define your own title page template.

The `beamer` documentation claims that your example should not insert space for the institute, but that is not the observed behaviour.

Setting up your own title page template is fortunately not too complex: use `\setbeamertemplate{title page}` and place the `beamer` generated commands such as `\inserttitle` etc. in a `center` environment.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{This is the title} 
\author{The name}
\date{The date}

\titlegraphic{%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
  {\begin{center}
      {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle}\\[1ex]
      {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor}\\[1ex]
      \insertdate\\
      \inserttitlegraphic
    \end{center}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*Update*
You now tell us you are using the `CambridgeUS` theme.  This loads the `innertheme` `rounded` which in turn calls the default `title page` template with extra options `colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow`.
The best thing to do in this situation is to take the default template, defined in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`, and define a new `title page` template by removing the `beamercolorbox` for the `institute`.  Calling this new template `noinstitute` you can then set the title page up with

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[noinstitute][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother
```

The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is need because of the `@` characters used in the internal names.

[image: Sample output for CambdrigeUS theme]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{This is the title} 
\author{The name}
\date{The date}

\titlegraphic{%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}}

\defbeamertemplate{title page}{noinstitute}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[noinstitute][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using the CambridgeUS-theme. How can I include the usual "box" behind the title?

Comment: Furthermore it seems, that the line spacing has changed. (I have a title, which is two lines long)

Comment: CambridgeUS set-up added.